# get child element in cypress

Tags: jquery, cypress

I want to get children element which has attribute name "tag-test" and value is "tab"

part of html I want to test is looks like below

```
  ... 
  <ul
     tag-test="tab"
  >
   <li  />
   <li  />
   <li  />
  />
```

thow can I get  last `li` from `ul` as a jquery object?

the below codes I console logged shows

  ...

how can I go further from

  ...

?

```
cy.get('ul[tag-test]=tab')
  .then((ul) => { 
     console.log(ul)  // <ul> ... </ul> . 
   })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To look for the last `li` within the `ul`, you can use the CSS pseudo-selector `last-child`.

For example, using this test fragment

```
<ul tag-test="tab">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>        // test should find this one
</ul>

<ul tag-test="another">
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>        // test should ignore this one
</ul>
```

the test could be

```
cy.get('ul[tag-test=tab]')
  .find('li:last-child')     // use find here to restrict search to previous subject
  .contains('3')
```

or to grab the jQuery object

```
cy.get('ul[tag-test=tab]')
  .find('li:last-child')
  .then($lastLI => {
    expect($lastLI).to.contain(3)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code I can see that locator for tag test is not correct, it should look like this:

```
cy.get('ul [tag-test="tab"]')
```

With this locator you will get all `ul` elements with attribute `tag-test="tab"`

Comment: There should be no space between the `ul` and the `[`. The space here means to match any `ul` element and then look for **any child** with the attribute `tag-test="tab"`. Without the space, it will find a `ul` element **that has** the attribute `tag-test="tab"`

Answer (score 0):

you can use **.find** solve our problem

In your case,

```
cy.get('ul[tag-test="tab"]')
.find('li')
  .then($li => {

     //$li will contain all the li elements inside your ul as an array
     cy.log($li)

     //if you want a specific li item use $li[index]
     cy.log($li[0])

     //if you want the last li item use the length of the returned li array
     cy.log($li[$li.lenght -1])

   })
```